# How do I enable/disable graphics card at will without logging out?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, kernel, graphics

My battery backup hardly lasts for 45mins. I searched for a similar problem but din't find any solution applicable to me.

I use Nvidia GeForce 525M graphics card and use Nouveau. My laptop gets heated up to about 85 deg (according to jupiter). Such a power consumption is too much for my battery.

Is there any way I can enable my graphics card and load my kernel module **only when needed without restart or logout**?
And till that time use only the integrated Intel graphics card.
(And I do not mean blacklisting as I would have to log out to enable it.)
I need a run-time loading and unloading of modules.

**Update :** I installed [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu) which increases the battery life to 2 hrs.(approx.) . However, I'd like to know how to load kernel modules after completing boot process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want Nvidia optimus, I believe it was recently added in the 304 driver release, so I recommend you install the nvidia driver.

Comment: Tried installing nvidia-current as per Q&As. Result was the same except that compiz effects were drastically reduced. I basically need one out of two things - either a driver which intelligently controls power or a way to do so manually. Still will try this.