# Ubuntu 12.04 high CPU usage and high temperature

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop uses more than 50 percents of each core even if nothing is running. I have checked from system monitor and from htop, both of them show that each of 4 CPUs percentage is above 50 percents. I have run sensors to check the temperature these are results when only firefox is running:

> acpitz-virtual-0 Adapter: Virtual device temp1:        +80.0°C  (crit
>   = +108.0°C)
>
> asus-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter temp1:        +80.0°C
>
> coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Physical id 0:  +82.0°C  (high
>   = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) Core 0:         +82.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) Core 1:         +74.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit =
>   +100.0°C)

What can be problem?

**EDIT:**
My Laptop:
ASUS U36SD RX167V
Intel Core i7-2620M 8GB RAM Nvidia Geforce GT520M

Bumblebee did not help

Comment: Post your specs in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be your graphics card consuming more power. I had a similar problem and I installed Bumblebee. Now I get approx. 2 hrs. of battery life and 65°C temp.(on prolonged use).

[Bumblebee's site](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu)

Also take a look at this : [How do I enable/disable graphics card at will without logging out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214891/how-do-i-enable-disable-graphics-card-at-will-without-logging-out)

Answer (score 0):

there are three links that saved me (all together!)  :)

for graphic card problems (i had an ATI Radeon):
http://techhamlet.com/2012/05/ubuntu-how-to-fix-over-heating-of-laptops-with-switchable-graphics/

as a power management utility:
installed jupiter with the following terminal commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

for updates:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2006241

these info all together made my laptop go back to normal temperatures.

Comment: the repository of jupiter not right. it provide error by add-apt-repository?! Any other links or repositories?