# high temperature with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, temperature

I don't know what is the problem but I  installed  14.04 and now the temperature is 78c any help please because this laptop will be burn my legs thanks

Comment: 78 is not really all that hot. Options are to clean out the vents or use a cooling pad.

Comment: Some specifications of your laptop could be useful. You can also look at these answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223127/ubuntu-12-04-high-cpu-usage-and-high-temperature || http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter…

Answer (score 1):

Your device or drivers can be old for Ubuntu 14.04. You should check this: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/ch02s01.html

And maybe you have to clean your GPU fan or CPU fan. And I recommend you dont use your laptop on top of your lap :-) Because fans need to circulate the air!

Answer (score 0):

My best advice to you will be to go out and buy a 'laptop cooling pad', a simple fan that can be place under a laptop to cool it more than the internal fan is capable of.

By the way, did you use this computer with some other operating system/ version of ubuntu without this problem?

Comment: yes with 13.10 it was cool